# How can i do add textbox dynamically in UserControl and how to focus in Wpf..?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I have developed an invoice application and I have added a Usercontrol with more than 2 textbox to my WPF Application.i'm using for search option in itemcode for  textbox1 and itemname showing textbox2 for getting value from database  data is showing successfully,now i need to textbox how to add dynamically in Usercontrol and focus to next row,if filled the 1 row then focus to next row.please find the below code what i made the mistake in the application please help me friends.Thank you advance

```
**Usercontrol.xaml**

<UserControl x:Class="InvoiceApp.UserControltest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="560" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="ItemHolder"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="250" Width="560">

        <TextBox x:Name="txtbx1" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111" KeyDown="txtbx1_KeyDown" BorderBrush="#FFC5C7CB" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbx2" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" BorderBrush="#FFC5C7CB" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbx3" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="201,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" BorderBrush="#FFC5C7CB"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbx4" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="285,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" BorderBrush="#FFC5C7CB" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbx5" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="369,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" BorderBrush="#FFC5C7CB" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbx6" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="453,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78" BorderBrush="#FFC5C7CB" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Margin="536,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFC5C7CB" />

    </Grid>

</UserControl>

**Usercontroltest.cs**



 private void txtbx1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)sender;
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Tax WHERE Tax=@tax", InvoiceApp.FrmBill.con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", txtbx.Text);
               // SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        txtbx2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();
                       // txtbx3.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                        txtbx3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tax"].ToString();
                        txtbx4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TaxAmount"].ToString();
                        txtbx5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
                      //  txtbx6.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
                       // txtId.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();
                        Items.Rows.Add(txtbx2.Text, txtbx3.Text, txtbx4.Text, txtbx5.Text);

                       // dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Items.DefaultView;
                        //dataGrid1.DataContext = Items;
                       // dattt();
                    }

                    //if (grdQustion.Rows.Count >= 1)
                    //{
                    //    int i = grdQustion.CurrentRow.Index + 1;
                    //    if (i >= -1 && i < grdQustion.Rows.Count)
                    //        grdQustion.CurrentCell = grdQustion.Rows[i].Cell[0];
                    //}
                }
                ds.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: It is hard to tell you how to do this without seeing your data model.

Comment: hi @RonBeyer thanks for your response i updated my question

Comment: WPF/UWP and XAML are designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into issues at every other corner. With MVVM this would not be a problem. Representing your data is never a problem in MVVM. I wrote a short introduction into MVVM a while back, it should be able to help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: i'm new in wpf @Christopher how to do MVVm pattern it's Easy.?

Comment: i need to add the textbox in datagrid cell in dynamically and search for item code display for itemname,uom,..etc

Comment: any other solutions please tell me

Comment: MVVM is different from most patterns I know. It has considerable upfront learning and development time. However it is totally worth it, especially if you plan to get any foot into WPF or UWP. Once you understand it, it seems so easy and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can add elements as children to an existing element. First create it, then at anytime change its properties and add into the element, here a Grid.

```
TextBox newchild = new TextBox();
ItemHolder.Children.Add(newchild);
```